# How to compile & run scala program in another scala program?

Tags: scala, compilation

I have a class in Scala and i want to compile and run this class in another Scala class. In Java code is:

```
   Process pro1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Main.java");
   pro1.waitFor();
   Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Main");
```

How i can do the same but for compile and run scala code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty close to the same.

```
val pro1 = sys.process.Process("scalac junk.sc")
if (pro1.! == 0)
  val pro2 = sys.process.Process("scala Main")
  println(pro2.!!)  // "Hello World"
else
  println("compile failed")
```

More options/details [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html).